# regex letters and numbers and characters jquery

Tags: jquery, regex

I have this regex jquery:

```
var regx = /^[\w ._-]+$/;
```

and

```
if( $($input).val().match(regx)) {
                                alert('it works fine');
                                }
else
   {
    alert('it does not works fine');
   return false
   e.preventDefault();
    }
```

Why if I write in input sth like e.j.:

```
Mary-Michael
```

I get an alert with **it does not works fine**, but If I write:

```
Mary.Michael or Mary_Michael
```

I get **it works fine**

I want add **- hyphen** to regex. Thank you

Comment: Seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/wv4qy/. The error must be in the part you are not showing us. Or you did not test it properly.

Comment: @FelixKling Is it possible that different JS engines treat the regex differently?

Comment: you are right I have the code error in other part. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hyphens have a special meaning in regex (like `[0-9]`) so you should escape it. You ought to escape the period, too, for that matter:

```
var regx = /^[\w \._\-]+$/;
```

Comment: Thank you too works fine. The error was in other code. Thank you!!

Comment: Inside character classes only `^` and `-` have a special meaning and only if they are at certain positions. This is the beginning of the class for `^` and between two characters for `-` (indicating a range). The regex here is absolutely correct, there is no need to escape these characters.

Comment: Inside character classes you do *not* have to escape the period (`[.]` matches literal `.`, not any character) and you do not have to escape hyphen when it's immediately followed by `]`

Comment: @FelixKling: `]` must also being escaped inside char class.

Comment: @FelixKling  I bow to your superior regex skills. That said, I prefer to escape those characters anywhere inside a regex to make sure *I* don't misunderstand their purpose, and because it's better to be safe than sorry.